# Typing http://localhost always redirects me to http://anonym.to

Tags: xampp

So I'm trying to install a local server to experiment on... Tried Wamp which gave this problem in the title (or so I thought).

Instead, I then tried installing Apache, and Xampp. Everything seems fine again. But when I type http://localhost into my browser (firefox, but for what it's worth the same thing happens with IE) it just redirects me to http://anonym.to/.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

That's some kind of anonymizer site that acts as a proxy server to browse anonymously.  You should probably check your /etc/hosts file to see if there is a redirect going on there for localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have an entry in your Windows Hosts file %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (entry which you can delete by editing this file) or your browser has proxy settings set (which you can unset).